# How to show these spaces are connected?

Tags: general-topology

Let $p:\mathbb{S}^n\to\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$ be the natural projection map, which is continuous, closed, open and surjective. I want to show it is a **covering map**.

Let $x\in \mathbb{S}^n$, and define $U=\{y\in\mathbb{S}^n:(x,y)\ne0\}$ where $(x,y)$ denotes the inner product of $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. Then $U$ is open in $\mathbb{S}^n$ and the sets $U_+=\{y\in\mathbb{S}^n:(x,y)>0\}$ and $U_-=\{y\in\mathbb{S}^n:(x,y)<0\}$ are disjoint, open and closed in $U$. I want to show they are the components of $U$, but i don't see how to show they are **connected**. I was thinking about finding a continous map whose domain is connected and whose image is, say, $U_+$; but I'm not able. Any hints or suggestion? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: How about starting with $y\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $\|y\|<1$, and $y\mapsto(\pm\sqrt{1-\|y\|^2},y)$. (I'm taking $x$ as the first axis.)

Comment: I guess you want to show that $p(U)$ is evenly covered with sheets $U_+, U_-$. If so, it is completely irrelevant that these sets are connected (although they are).

Comment: @Chrystomath Your map works for the case $x=(1,0)$ and I can adapt it when $x=(0,1,0,\dots,0)$ and so on, but I don't see how to generalize it for an arbitrary $x \in \mathbb{S}^n$. Is there a "geometric construction" which I might follow?

Comment: @PaulFrost Yes, you are right! :) I know that if $X$ is a topological space and $S$ is a non empty subset of $X$ which is open and closed in $X$, then $S$ is union of components of $X$. If $S$ is also connected, then $S$ is itself a component of $X$. So how can I skip verifying the connectedness of $U_+$ and $U_-$?

Comment: @PaulFrost The definition of covering map I'm using require evenly covered sets to be connected

Comment: We're all... like... connected... whoa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define $V_+ = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \mid (x,y) > 0 \}$ It is easy to verify that this set is convex, hence path connected (and especially connected). Moreover $U_+ \subset V_+ \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{ 0 \}$. We have a retraction $r : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus \{ 0 \} \to S^n, r(y) = y/\lVert y \rVert$. Trivially $U_+ = r(U_+) \subset r(V_+)$. In fact, we have $r(V_+) = U_+$:
If $(x,y) > 0$, then $(x,r(y)) = (x,y/\lVert y \rVert) = (x,y)/\lVert y \rVert > 0$.
This shows that $U_+$ is connected.

The connectedness of $U_-$ is shown analogously.

**Remark:**

You mentioned in your comments that the definition of covering map you are using requires evenly covered sets to be connected. In my opinion this is unusual. However, if the base space $X$ of $p : Y \to X$ is *locally connected*, then this agrees with the usual definition. To see this, take any open neigborhood $U$ of $x$ which is evenly covered, i.e. $p^{-1}(U)$ is the disjoint union of open $V_\alpha$ which are mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U$.  By local connectedness there is a connected open neighborhood $U'$ of $x$ such that $U' \subset U$. Let $V'_\alpha = p^{-1}(U') \cap V_\alpha$. Then $U'$ is evenly covered with connected sheets $V'_\alpha$.

What might be the reason to use your definition? If you require the sheets to be connected, then they are the components of $p^{-1}(U)$. In particular, the set of sheets is uniquely determined. This is no longer true for non-connected sheets: You will find various decompositions of $p^{-1}(U)$ into disjoint open sets which are mapped by $p$ homeomorphically onto $U$.

In your question $S^n$ is locally connected and $p$ is easily seen to be an open map, hence also $\mathbb{P}^n(\mathbb{R})$ is locally connected.

Comment: Great, elementary, rigorous and elegant, and thank you for your remark :) Yes, my defininition of covering map $p:E\to X$ require $X$ connected and locally path- connected  :)

Answer (score 1):

Let $E:\mathbb{R}^n\to x^\perp\subset\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ be a linear isometry ($x^\perp$ is $n$-dimensional). Then the map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{S}^n$ defined by $$f(y):=\sqrt{1-\|y\|^2}x/\|x\|+Ey$$ is continuous and maps the open unit disk onto $U_+$. Note that $$\|f(y)\|^2=(1-\|y\|^2)+\|y\|^2=1$$ since $Ey\perp x$. Also for any $p\in U_+$, take $\|x\|=1$ without loss of generality, and let $y:=E^{-1}(p-\langle p,x\rangle x)$, then $$\|y\|^2=\|p-\langle p,x\rangle x\|^2=1-\langle p,x\rangle^2<1$$ and $f(y)=\langle p,x\rangle x+p-\langle p,x\rangle x=p$.

Comment: Very beautiful, thank- you :)